# My jquery code does not work after for loop

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to iterate through some `textbox`es in a form using jQuery. It was working fine the other day and suddenly stopped working. I understand something has happened wrong for sure but couldn't identify. Please help me out of this trouble if you see the error
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$serial = 0;
while ($row_details = mysql_fetch_array($res_details)) {
    $serial++;
    $remaining_qty = $row_details['ordered_qty'] - $row_details['received_qty'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $serial . '.<input type="hidden" name="pcode-' . $serial . '" id="pcode-' . $serial . '" value="' . $row_details['product_code'] . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row_details['product_name'] . ' [' . $row_details['product_code'] . ']</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row_details['ordered_qty'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row_details['received_qty'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $remaining_qty . '<input type="hidden" name="remain-' . $serial . '" id="remain-' . $serial . '" value="' . $remaining_qty . '"/></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="newreceive-' . $serial . '" id="newreceive-' . $serial . '" size="5" class="money-field" value="' . $remaining_qty . '"/></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = <?php echo $serial; ?>;// count is the no of rows
var verified = true;
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    if ($("#pcode-" + i).val().length > 0) {
        if (parseInt($("#remain-" + i).val()) < parseInt($("#newreceive-" + i).val())) {
            verified = false;
        }
    }
    alert("Iteration" + i);
}

/* After this line the code does not works*/
alert("inside verify()");
if (verified) {
    alert("Verification successful");
    $("#update").removeAttr('disabled');
}
else {
    alert("Verification failed");
    $("#update").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
</script>
```

This is inside a function `verify()` which is called on a button click. The code does not work after the `for` loop.

Comment: Did you get any error in `console`? Show us your `HTML` also.

Comment: Thanks Gautam3164 for the code format.

Comment: I actually tried it inside a php script and put some alert() to see where it stopped working. It works fine before the line `alert("inside verify()");`

Comment: What is `count`? Is `alert("inside verify()");` firing? Is either of `alert("Verification successful");` or `alert("Verification failed");` firing? And what is not working - is the button not being enabled/disabled? Give an example o test cases -where it should pass & fail?

Comment: No Daredev. `alert("inside verify()");` is not firing. And neither of the rest of alerts is firing. Thats the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. Strange - neither of the alerts is firing? Can you `alert()` value of `verified` (for instance - using `alert("inside verify() "+verified)` )?

Comment: Did you get the `alert` in `for loop`?

Comment: might want  to wrap the inline script in a document.ready call as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `parseInt` for `count` and the `loop` should `break` after `verified=false;` like,

```
var count = <?php echo $serial; ?>;// count is the no of rows
var verified = true;
for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(count); i++) {// parseInt the count
    if ($("#pcode-" + i).val().length > 0) {
        if (parseInt($("#remain-" + i).val()) < parseInt($("#newreceive-" + i).val())) {
            verified = false;
            break;// break the loop if your validation fails
        }
    }
    alert("Iteration" + i);
}
```

**Updated** try this I tested it works at my end

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var count = <?php echo $serial; ?>;// count is the no of rows
        var verified = true;
        for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(count); i++) {
            if ($("#pcode-" + i).val().length > 0) {
                if (parseInt($("#remain-" + i).val()) < parseInt($("#newreceive-" + i).val())) {
                    verified = false;break;
                }
            }
            alert("Iteration" + i);
        }

        /* After this line the code does not works*/
        alert("inside verify()");
        if (verified) {
            alert("Verification successful");
            $("#update").removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            alert("Verification failed");
            $("#update").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder, what causes the code not executing lines after `for` loop. I tried any line after for loop, doesn't work!!

Comment: Did you get the `alert` in `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. Actually I messed up the value of `count` as I placed **another php script** in the page that also uses `$serial` and updates it. Thats why the value of `count` also changes and results my jquery code to malfunction.

Sorry... folks. It was a silly mistake.;-)